# CPU Scheduling incredibly slow with large difference between total execution time and actual CPU time - Ubuntu Full-Disk Encryption enabled

Tags: ubuntu, cpu, scheduling, disk-encryption

Admittedly, I am running on a build that is no younger than five years old at this point and the system is not going to be incredibly fast. However, at the same time, the run-times I am observing are so painfully slow it's urged me to create this question to see if there was something I could do to fix this problem.

For example, I was simply unpacking a tarball, albeit quite a large one (~15GB), and the entire process **took about 2.5 hours with about 9 minutes of actual CPU time**. In contrast, the creation of this tarball took about just a few minutes. Again, the creation was on a fairly adept machine, but 2.5 hours seems far too slow.

As a second example, building a particular project (on the adept machine) took only 19 seconds, with 17 of those seconds being actual CPU time. In contrast, the same process **took nearly 9 minutes (on this slower machine) with only about 14 seconds being actual CPU time**. As you can see below, the actual CPU time is fairly similar, it's just the total execution time that is the problem.

`Adept Machine`

```
real    0m19.245s
user    0m15.809s
sys     0m0.908s
```

`Current Machine`

```
real    8m37.500s
user    0m11.175s
sys     0m3.969s
```

I include the unfair comparison between the two machines only as a reference point. There is nothing particularly amazing about the *adept* machine, it's just quite a bit newer. The current machine has 4 GB of RAM; the adept machine has quite a bit more as it is a server, but only 2 GB of RAM is actually being used. There's no disk I/O, the above performance happens when the machine is otherwise idle.

Ubuntu in general tends to be quite a bit more sluggish than it should be, often times freezing for a few moments before resuming. Opening tasks tends to take a lot of time as well - as much as 20-30 seconds for something as simple as Eclipse; browsers can take 5-10 seconds as well.

- Ubuntu 14.04 -- **Full-disk encryption enabled**
- Core i-7 860 @ 2.8Ghz
- WD2500JS 7200RPM SATA 3Gbps 8MB Cache

**tldr; Why is there such a huge gap between total execution time and actual CPU time? The disk I am using is not that slow. It's hard to believe the disk being the source of such a huge discrepancy. Perhaps it's the first-gen i7?**

---

Updates based on feedback in comments:

- Tried `tar -t`, but after 6 minutes of waiting I killed it. Total CPU time: 3 seconds in user space.
- `taf -tf` actually delivers output to the terminal and changes the output of `iostat`, but only 20-30 Kb/s.
- No error messages in the system log about filesystem corruption or disk timeouts
- Unlike `iostat`, `iotop` actually gives results and shows 80-90% IO and 30-40 MB/s when listing contents with `tar` and redirecting it to `/dev/null`.

Comment: Hard to say without knowing what kind of resources are being exhausted.  RAM can be one of them.  I/O bandwidth can be another.  Are you trying to unpack that 15 GB tar on a filesystem with sync operations?  Does it create thousands of small files?  Do you have several processes fighting over disk to access disk at the same time?

Comment: @lcd047, watching the RAM usage during the build process or tarball unpacking shows that only about half (~2GB) is actually being used at any time. Not sure regarding the sync operations, but no special parameters were passed during packing or unpacking (tar -(c)xf ..).

Comment: As I said, find out what resources are being exhausted.  My bet is on I/O, but there can be other causes too.  The options to `tar` are irrelevant, what is relevant is what fs you have and how you mount it.

Comment: Could you run `iostat 5` during the build for a few moments and see what the max read and write speeds are?

Comment: Hmm, `tar t` can be slow because console writes can be slow, so this can be misleading.  Try something like `tar tf file.tar >/dev/null`, is that still slow?

Comment: Forget about the CPU time, this is clearly not CPU-bound.

Comment: Well, I don't expect `tar t` to use much CPU time, but I'd be interested in seeing what `iostat` shows as the read rate when you run that `tar`.

Comment: @lcd047, I was just making a point to show that it was never getting CPU time at all. The baseline before starting `tar -t` on the tarball is `555 kB/s read` and `580 kB/s write`. After starting `tar -t` there are no substantial changes. Actually, none it seems. I ran this: `watch -n 0.5 iostat` and before/after running `tar -t` I find that no changes are observed aside from a tenth or so either way for both read/write.

Comment: I meant `tar t` and `tar x` as shorthands for `tar tf file.tar` and `tar xf file.tar`.  Plain `tar t` is supposed to read from a tape, and I suppose you don't have one installed. :)

Comment: Right: full-disk encryption might be your problem.  A dying disk might be another explanation (even if you don't see messages about it in the logs).

Comment: Sorry, when I said `tar t`, I meant `tar tf pathtoyourfile.tar`.

Comment: OK. Can you do another tar extraction of the multi-gigabyte file for a couple minutes and see what the read and write rates reported by iotop are?